# Is there a way to use .strip and .replace with csv.reader

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am trying to read some data from a csv file and the sort in in numerical order and print it. It works but it is really messy and i want to clean up the output is there a way to do this.

```
    file = open(class_name, "r")
    csv1 = csv.reader(file)
        def arange():
            for line in sort:
                #line = line.strip().replace(","," ") THIS IS WHAT I USE FOR OTHER PARTS OF MY CODE
                print (line)


    sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda z:(int(z[1]),z[0]),reverse=True)
    # I use this to sort it
```

The syntax might be wrong but that is because I don't want to use my whole code as an example

Comment: can you fix your indentation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `csv.reader` can be thought of as a list of lists. The outer list gives rows, while the inner lists give cells, e.g.

```
one, two, three
four, five, six
```

becomes

```
[ ["one", "two", "three"],
  ["four", "five", "six"] ]
```

You can see then that `line` is a list, not a string, and therefore doesn't have a `strip` or `replace` method! It seems like what you want to do is:

```
for line in sort:
    print(" ".join(line))
```

Which will yield:

```
one two three
four five six
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, i dont think i would have got it